# After logging in 'User.Identity.Name' is null, but 'IsAuthenticated' is true when using Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc integration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, sustainsys-saml2

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, and need to support SAML 2.0 authentication. I am evaluating [Sustainsys.Saml.Mvc](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/). The `User.Identity.Name` property in my controller is an empty string, while the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property is `true`, and can't for the life of me figure it out.

While installing the Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc NuGet package, I had to do the following things:

1. Upgrade the .NET framework from 4.5.1 to 4.6.1
2. Install Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc v2.2.0
3. Upgrade the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc package from 5.2.3 to 5.2.7
4. Tweaked Web.config settings according to the [Sustainsys.Saml2 documentation](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/2.0/configuration.html)
5. Downloaded the .cert and .pfx files from their demo MVC application

Contents of Web.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="sustainsys.saml2" type="Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.SustainsysSaml2Section, Sustainsys.Saml2" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    ...
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Saml2/SignIn" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="ABC">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ABC" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" path="Authorization/Permissions/*" verb="GET,POST" />
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension="eot" />
      <remove fileExtension="otf" />
      <remove fileExtension="woff" />
      <remove fileExtension="woff2" />
      <remove fileExtension="ttf" />
      <remove fileExtension="json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="otf" mimeType="application/x-font-opentype" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="ttf" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </modules>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>
  <sustainsys.saml2 entityId="http://localhost/MyMvcApp/Saml2" returnUrl="http://localhost/MyMvcApp/">
    <identityProviders>
      <add entityId="https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/Metadata" signOnUrl="https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
        <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/stubidp.sustainsys.com.cer" />
      </add>
    </identityProviders>
    <!--<federations>
      <add metadataLocation="http://localhost:52071/Federation" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true"/>
    </federations>-->
    <serviceCertificates>
      <add fileName="~/App_Data/Sustainsys.Saml2.Tests.pfx" />
    </serviceCertificates>
  </sustainsys.saml2>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.121.2.0" newVersion="4.121.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" from="foo@mycompany.com">
        <network host="smtp.mycompany.com" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="..." />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <elmah>
    <!--
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for
        more information on remote access and securing ELMAH.
    -->
    <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.MemoryErrorLog, Elmah" size="50" />
  </elmah>
  <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <!--
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for
        more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.-->
      <authorization>
        <allow users="..." />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I'm currently hosting my application from my laptop:

- Windows 10 Enterprise
- .NET framework up to 4.6.1 is installed
- IIS 10.0.15063.0
- Application pool settings in IIS:

  - .NET 4.0
  - Allow 32-bit applications

It is using the mock Identity Provider at: https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/

The XML posted to /MyApp/Saml2/Acs:

```xml
<saml2p:Response Destination="http://localhost/MyApp/Saml2/Acs" ID="idb4440bf88fba449f8526760d4330dd53" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2018-12-20T18:21:22Z" InResponseTo="idd9b8948ac5ac4c389bf65072169464ac"
    xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer
        xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/Metadata
    </saml2:Issuer>
    <Signature
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <Reference URI="#idb4440bf88fba449f8526760d4330dd53">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>...</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:Assertion
        xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Version="2.0" ID="_d6ffcd18-44ec-45db-bd74-9cf48ea1cfa2" IssueInstant="2018-12-20T18:21:22Z">
        <saml2:Issuer>https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/Metadata</saml2:Issuer>
        <saml2:Subject>
            <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">JohnDoe</saml2:NameID>
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-20T18:23:22Z" InResponseTo="..." Recipient="http://localhost/MyApp/Saml2/Acs" />
            </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:Conditions NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-20T18:23:22Z">
            <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml2:Audience>http://localhost/MyApp/Saml2</saml2:Audience>
            </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml2:Conditions>
        <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-12-20T18:21:22Z" SessionIndex="42">
            <saml2:AuthnContext>
                <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml2:AuthnContext>
        </saml2:AuthnStatement>
    </saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

I also set the `Options.Logger` property on the controller, and this is what I'm getting in the debug output:

```
[Saml2, DEBUG]: Http POST binding extracted message
<saml2p:Response Destination="http://localhost/MyApp/Saml2/Acs" ...>...</saml2p:Response>
[Saml2, DEBUG]: Signature validation passed for Saml Response Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Id
[Saml2, DEBUG]: Extracted SAML assertion _a5ee9c7f-4ca5-4693-a7f7-301ae5e6d4a6
[Saml2, INFO]: Successfully processed SAML response Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Id and authenticated JohnDoe
```

While debugging the application, the `User.Identity.Name` property in my MVC controller is null. Further inspection of that object:

[image: Screenshot of debug console in Visual Studio]

**Why is `System.Web.Mvc.Controller.User.Identity.Name` null after successfully asserting the SAML response?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have properly completed the authentication. And you have a working session authentication cookie.

What you don't have however is a claim that matches the default name claim type. You have the NameIdentifier claim (which is what the stub idp supplies by default). But you don't have a claim with the default `NameClaimType`

The `Name` property of a `ClaimsIdentity` is implemented as

```
return Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == NameClaimType)?.Value;
```

So to get a value on the `Name` property you either need to change the `NameClaimType` (can be done by modifying the created identity in the `AcsCommandResultCreated` notification) or get your Idp to provide an attribute of type `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name`. You can do that by adding an attribute at the bottom of the stubidp form.

Comment: That's interesting. I'm going to poke around in the Sustainsys code a little more to see if I just need to pass a customer key=value pair through the fake identity provider, or if there is a defect in the NuGet package. I figured their fake identity provider would pretty much work out-of-the box, but I guess not.

Comment: *My* fske identity provider works out of the box with *my* library. But by default, it only provides the bare minimum that is required by the SAML2 standard. The `ClaimsIdentity.Name` property expects another attribute. I actually considered this a feature when implementing the stubidp: to see how asp.net behaves with only the minimum information required by SAML2.

Comment: Apparently ASP.NET leaves a little to be desired. I am looking to integrate with a SAML2 identity provider that isn't written in the .NET stack. I wonder if this will be an issue integrating with the real solution too. I added an attribute named `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name` with the value of my username, and things are working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using Identity server, but same basic issue:

Look at your Claims under `User.Identity.Claims` and find one that does have your username.

[image]

Then wherever you configure the tokenvalidation you have to put the `NameClaimType` to be the one you saw above:

Then when the middleware validates it it will copy that claim into `UserName`. I'm assuming this is some default for Windows authentication [sic].

```
   var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
   {
            NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem with Core 3.1: The User.Identity.Name property is null, while the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true. But you can get the name by using the HttpContectAccessor in your controller:

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public MyController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
   _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}

public void AnyMethod()
{
  var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
  var user = _context.AspNetUsers.Find(userId);
  var name = user.UserName;
  ...
}
```

In Startup.cs add the service:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```